# Magento2 - Buy y get x for x off where y is one simple product and x is another

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

How we can set up the following?

Buy `y` get `x` for `x` off where `y` is one simple product and `x` is another.

Selling clothing different sizes and want to sell one size for a discount if we buy another.

Comment: can you provide some more information in your question such as the version of Magento you are using.